# How do I Get My Blender Model to Save in Current state

Tags: modeling

Ok so I'm working on a model and when I Render the model, or save and quit, then come black later everything I did in the previous Session (Session's before save and quiting) Goes to the 3d cursor.

I've tried Applying Scale, Rotation.
I've tried Setting Origin to Geometry.
I've tried Clearing parent and Keeping Transformation.

Any help is appreciated thx.
Picture 1 Is before save and quitting /before rendering.
[[image: Unbroken Model1]
Picture 2 Is After save and quitting /After rendering.
[image: Broken Model]

Comment: Hi :). It looks like you have all your transforms keyframed. Could that be the issue?

Comment: How would i got about undoing said suggestion?? if that is it

Comment: Hover over the transform field RMB > Remove Keyframes

Comment: Thank you so much thought I would have to start over

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is in the timeline window. You just delete the keyframe and be sure to have that record button disabled if you're not going to use it.
Make sure to grab the timeline screen with the middle mouse and scroll to top right corner, zoom out and expand the section where you can see the 'Summary' item on the screenshot so you can see the whole timeline.
Go to 'View' and disable 'Only keyframes from selected channel' in the timeline so you can see the keyframes of all the objects not just the one you selected.
You can also try to use shortcuts A (Select all toggle), X (Delete) and Del(,)(zoom into selection) to be sure there are not a single keyframe left.

[image: timeline]

All these yellow colors indicates that you keyframed those properties on the current frame so either you added it from the menu or the record was enabled at some point or maybe bc it's an imported file. Cleaning just the transforms might not be enough bc all the properties could be keyframed.

[image]